# Javascript 100% width drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to try and achieve a 100% width drop down for my wordpress menu.

My issue is that my wordpress menu has a structure like this with the sub menu ul nested within the list for my nav.

```
<li><a href="">menu-1</a> 
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li>sub 1</li>
<li>sub 2</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

The dropdown will only work if my sub menu is not nested within the top level navigation list like this.

```
<li><a href="">menu-1</a> </li>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li>sub 1</li>
<li>sub 2</li>
</ul>
```

[My fiddle of the drop working on menu 1 and not working on menu 2](http://jsfiddle.net/S7n2b/182/)

How can i change my script so that the drop down works with the current (html structure the sub menu UL inside the list tags) I really don't want to edit my wordpress menu and I'm not sure how to change the html for this aswell.

Comment: remove all the cruft from the fiddle as it makes it too hard to read. Also maybe indent it properly. Make it easy for us to help you.

Comment: @2pha Hi, I wanted to leave the classes in from wordpress has this is the html I have to work with and they may be needed for the script? Any ideas?

Comment: the problem is with your use of `$(hovered).next('.sub-menu')` which will not select the submenu if it is a child. Using `$(hovered).children('.sub-menu')` works.

Comment: Also, instead of always using `$(hovered)`, put it into a variable with `hovered = $(this);` and then use `hovered` instead of `$(hovered)`. No need to call JQuery so many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the sub-menu thing [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S7n2b/188/)

the structure you want can be achieved through JS, all you needed to do is grab the submenu's nested within the `.menu-item`'s and insert them after their [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) which is `.menu-item` by using [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)

There is however another issue which is out of the context of the question, which you can always add to the question ofcourse ;) - the menu animation is overlapping the next one rather than first animating one out before the other is animated in.

Furthermore for UX I would recommend you increase the speed of the menu animation, `350ms` isn't exactly fast, it's `50ms` faster than jQueries default animation speed.

I would increase this to be about 150ms max - but that's just advice ;)

**EDIT**

After reading @2pha's comments to your question, this is also something to note.

You could have used jQueries [`hovered.children('.sub-menu')`](http://api.jquery.com/children/), or [`hovered.find('.sub-menu')`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the right element. Ofcourse this only works if you don't have `overflow: hidden` within the main menu's `li`'s.

(on a sidenote - jQueries `.find()` is the faster method until you start nesting deeply.)

Then there's also the caching of variables which you could take into account.

jQuery is a library that turns a DOM node into a jQuery collection (array of jQuery objects) that all have loaded functions. each time you call `$(selector)` you're creating a fresh new object. This isn't that heavy but if you do this alot your website could easily lag on a mobile platform.

If you're going to use something more than once or maybe twice, put the selector in a variable as @2pha noted: `var hovered = $(hovered)`.

Then simply use `hovered.someJQmethod()` - this uses the cached object instead of a fresh instance, which saves alot of resources esp for phones ;).

I want to state that this answer got a whole lot bigger thanks to @2pha's input in the comments. Give him credit if you're giving me credit ;)

Good luck and hope this helps ;)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help (with a little assistance too). Your question was quite alright and could be confusing to figure out when looking @ WP markup. It's the main reason I don't work with WP - all the bloat ;) but I'm sure they're getting better as well!

Comment: I got the menu working within wordpress , the issue I have now is that my sub menu on my footer is disappearing when i go over any of the nav links in the footer or top menu. Is there a way I can stop this, my footer ID is #menu-footer-menu. This is the exact same html structure as the top menu, just the ID of the UL is #menu-footer-menu rather than #menu-main-navigation. Hope that helps. I need some little bit of code to make the footer exempt @Sidney ?

Comment: WP uses the same classes for the header and footer menu - most likely anyways ;) so what you want to do is take the JS you've written and apply it to a more specific selector so that only your header will be affected by the changes. You can do this by using the ID in the header menu in the selector `$('#menu-main-navigation .menu-item')` - only the `.menu-item`'s inside the `#menu-main-navigation` will be affected ;) Make sure your footer doesn't share the same ID tho! (change line 13 in my linked fiddle)

Comment: Thank you again @Sidney . Bit silly of me not think of that before. I added the ID for the menu to all instances where sub-menu was mentioned and that did the trick. Just changing line 13 didn't help initially. You're a great guy, many thanks.

Comment: Hope it helped you out, it's what this community is for! - be careful not to duplicate ID's tho (unexpected JS behaviour etc..) - if My answer in any way had a positive effect I would like you to consider the upvote button ;)